# App crashes if we try to logout Twitter Digit API in Android

Tags: android, logout, twitter-digits

I have integrated Twitter Digit API for mobile number verification.

I have used DigitsAuthButton in my code as below :

```
  final DigitsAuthButton digitsButton = (DigitsAuthButton) findViewById(R.id.auth_button);

        digitsButton.setCallback(new AuthCallback() {
            @Override
            public void success(DigitsSession session, String phoneNumber) {
                // TODO: associate the session userID with your user model
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication successful for "
                        + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                try {
                    Digits.logout();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void failure(DigitsException exception) {
                Log.d("Digits", "Sign in with Digits failure", exception);
            }
        });
```

But, my app crashes when the compiler reaches to `Digits.logout();

However, I didn't find any type of crash log in my log.

Can you please advice me.

Thank you.

Comment: did you check whether user is authenticate or not before LogOut?

Comment: What do you mean by user is authenticate? Means once all process completes, the callback calls it's success method that means everything goes fine for authentication. Is it you are talking about?

Comment: i mean, check for if(Digits.isDigitsUser())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got the solution.

All I needed was I just delayed the execution of Digit API logout.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Digits.logout();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, 3000);
```

Thank you all for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Digits.clearActiveSession();` instead of  `Digits.logout();`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have tried but still not working, app still crashes.